# Maximum possible file size in the filesystem

Tags: operating-systems, filesystems

A file system with 300GByte disk uses a file descriptor with 8 direct block address ,1 indirect block address and 1 doubly indirect block address. The size of each disk block is 128 Bytes and the size of each disk block address is 8 Bytes.What is the maximum possible file size in this filesystem?
This is previous year question I could not get the idea and couldn't solve it...plz help

Comment: This is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answers [here](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2008/12/24/understanding-indirect-blocks-in-unix-file-systems) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812708/the-concept-of-inodes-and-block-sizes)

I should have posted this as comment but I don't have enough reputation points.